# Would this question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

On public (and other) buildings which have extensive glass walls, you sometimes see the silhouettes of flying birds affixed to the glass.

My understanding is:

- This is intended to deter birds from flying into the glass and hurting themselves
- Officials doing this is an implicit (i.e. unspoken) but obvious claim, that this method is effective (i.e. it is a claim that, and/or is the result of a claim that, affixing bird silhouettes to glass is effective at helping to deter birds from flying into the glass)

Is this a sufficient "notable claim" for the main site -- can I just state this observation, and ask what evidence for the claimed effect?

Or must I find some explicit, wordy claim on that subject?

Comment: No need for an implicit claim, when there is an explicit one: https://www.amazon.com/Birds-Choice-Birdsaver-Window-Decals/dp/B001QIVXW4. However, this doesn't actually answer your meta question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply find evidence that many people believe the claim you ...claim. Don't just assume they do.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Having looked for evidence, I no longer need to ask that question.

Comment: @ChrisW So what's the answer?  Now I'm curious.